# Help understanding a simple control circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

I come from a non-electronics background and I'm interested in understanding the operation of the following circuit configuration. The drawing is very crude, but this is the representation that I have available:

[image]

I do recognize some elements, like the resistance and the ground (lower pointing triangle.) The left-pointing triangle seems to be an op-amp from a quick search in Google. Besides the translation, I'd like to have a clear idea of how this circuit would work.

Could you please help me out decoding this?

Comment: Where did you find this?

Comment: The circuit image in the question makes little sense to me.

Comment: Not enough context to suggest an application of this circuit. But "V" *must* be an input, which by default, makes "I" an output. The left-pointing triangle might indeed be a standard opamp. It *might* also be a transconductance-type amplifier (which has voltage inputs, and current output).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would have been nice if you had labelled the circuit. If you are new to this, generally you label nodes at the intersection of wires connecting different components.

Here's how the circuit would work. Assume voltage at non-inverting lower terminal of OP-amp be \$V_a\$ and at the upper terminal \$V_b\$. \$V_b\$ is connected to ground so current will flow from current source I through the resistor R.

Attached is a circuit diagram assuming some values for V,I and R. You have to rotate this circuit 180 degrees to get your circuit diagram.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you mind explaining the use of the resistance in this type of circuit?

Comment: This circuit is peculiar because current flowing in resistor R is not I. if you increase I in your diagram, the current flowing in the reisistor R is not changed , it is somewhat lower in mA range. This circuit seems to give constant current in resistor R with variation in V and I so it can be used as  current source or a crude current regulator. This behavior has something to with op amp characteristics.